# public or protected to replace var

Tags: php

I'm updating some code for php 7.2 and I've come across some previously updated code that has me somewhat confused.

An snippet of an older version of code is

```
/**
 * Maintains a list of any URI mappings for the Manufacturer which clash with existing mappings.
 *
 * @var     array
 * @access  protected
 */
 var $_clashing_mappings = array();
```

A slightly later version of the same code segment has been changed to

```
/**
 * Maintains a list of any URI mappings for the Manufacturer which clash with existing mappings.
 *
 * @var     array
 * @access  protected
 */
 public $_clashing_mappings = array();
```

Given that the original authors notes say "@access protected", shouldn't the updated code be

```
protected $_clashing_mappings = array();
```

Should it indeed be protected, and what are the implications of declaring it public instead of protected?

Comment: The short version is "maybe?" - it all depends on the context of the code around it. If it was declared protected initially, but then other code written that assumed it was public (when `var` wasn't providing any meaningful protection), then it may be that `protected` was the *intended* result, but not the one required for the code to run as-is. Such is the vagaries of software maintenance. Take a look at what other things reference the variable.

Comment: Search all the code that uses the class for `->_clashing_mappings`. Make sure that they're all in the class or subclasses. If they are, it should be safe to make it protected.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP document should be match your source.

```
/**
 * @access public
 */
public $var;
//or
/**
 * @access protected
 */
protected $var;
```